# Strange NTSC frame timestamps in Mp4 video

Tags: video, mp4, android-mediacodec, ntsc

I am investigating a mp4 video taken on Android Samsung tablet. I have used MediaCodec and MediaExtractor to get some detailed info about it and found some interesting things which don't make sense to me. The NTSC video seems to be 1080p/29.97fps. I made a list of frames together with the MediaExtractor.SampleTime info. Here is the list:

```
0-KEY timestamp: 0
1- timestamp: 36711  diff:36711
2- timestamp: 70022  diff:33311
3- timestamp: 103322  diff:33300
4- timestamp: 136655  diff:33333
5- timestamp: 169955  diff:33300
6- timestamp: 203300  diff:33345
7- timestamp: 236588  diff:33288
8- timestamp: 269955  diff:33367
9- timestamp: 303244  diff:33289
10- timestamp: 336577  diff:33333
11- timestamp: 369855  diff:33278
12- timestamp: 403166  diff:33311
13- timestamp: 436511  diff:33345
14- timestamp: 469800  diff:33289
15- timestamp: 503111  diff:33311
16- timestamp: 536477  diff:33366
17- timestamp: 569733  diff:33256
18- timestamp: 603055  diff:33322
19- timestamp: 636388  diff:33333
20- timestamp: 669700  diff:33312
21- timestamp: 703000  diff:33300
22- timestamp: 736311  diff:33311
23- timestamp: 769633  diff:33322
24- timestamp: 802944  diff:33311
25- timestamp: 836311  diff:33367
26- timestamp: 869577  diff:33266
27- timestamp: 902933  diff:33356
28- timestamp: 936211  diff:33278
29- timestamp: 969522  diff:33311
30-KEY timestamp: 1002833  diff:33311
```

The interesting fact is that the duration of the frames varies more than I would expect. I thought the duration should be something like 1 / (30 / 1001) milliseconds ~33.366ms.
But as I can see the first frame is ~36.711ms for example. And what is much more interesting for me is the fact that the 30th (zero based) frame starts at 1.002833 second. 
Shouldn't it start at 1.001 second? 
Can anybody recommend me some articles about NTSC video in digital form? Am I missing something important or are the timestamps in my example somehow non-standard?

Originally I was thinking about whether I am able to compute the stream time to seek from a number of frames which I would skip. Let's say that I want to skip 27 frames of the mp4 stream. What is the time I should seek to? And I ended up looking at the list of frames and wondering what's going on :)

Comment: Perhaps you could just share a link to a sample file.

Answer (score 1):

Your thought process is rite on, but you’re missing one thing. Most software sucks. What you are saying is true, but whoever wrote the software that produced that mp4 doesn’t care, or know how to properly package a file. Sadly the majority of video files in the wild are like this.

Try to average all the durations, it probably comes really close to 30000/1001

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for the replies, my apologies, I've got the information that it is 29.97, but after having chance to look at another video of the same type, I found out that this must be definitely a variable frame rate video. (second video has one frame with duration 466333us) 
Anyway, since it is a live capture video (not a presentation of static pictures or something like this), I don't see the point why the  the frame durations don't vary in multiples of a fixed frame rate. Like frame0 = 33.366ms and frame1 = 66.732 (33.366 * 2) for example. 
Wondering how easy it is to transcode such videos to different framerate formats like 23/24/25/29.97 :)